# Google Sheets - extract text between two characters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a form connected to Google Sheets which is populating a dynamic matrix into a single column per row for a customer claim. E.g. one customer claim by PO number for a number of products (containing SKU name, article number, UoM, quantity)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNQWv.png)

I want to split out each item by customer, PO number and reason for claim (see desired outcome tab in spreadsheet) like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V8Im.png)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NeVdCVA0oayx1D3UC8WBxv4SJtrZiTyOf2v3zpnN2Sc/edit#gid=219062088

The formula I am trying to use split the products removing the text before is
=(IFERROR(ArrayFormula(((REGEXEXTRACT(F2,": (.+)"))SPLIT(E2:E, ",")), " ")))

I still haven't worked out how transpose into a new table format. Any help much appreciated :)

Comment: the spreadsheet you shared can't be accessed. Pease fix permissions.

Comment: try this formula `=ArrayFormula(query(split(transpose(split(Join(char(10);E2:E);char (10)));",:");"select Col2,Col4,Col6,Col8"))`

Comment: Hi @JPV sorry had restrictions limited please see spreadsheet below https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g2gJ2lwSV0biCilPipgovarjK7qDzIO-QfQHbWpvnM4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Cheers @Sergey ! That worked well. The only other thing I need is for each row to be associated with the customer name and PO number and reason for claim i.e. Columns A B and C - do you know how I could achieve that? Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sheet 'JPV Help' I entered

```
=ArrayFormula(query(split(regexreplace(flatten(iferror('Product Breakdown'!A2:A&"/ "&substitute('Product Breakdown'!B2:B, "po",)&"/ "&'Product Breakdown'!C2:C&"/ "&split('Product Breakdown'!D2:D, char(10)))), "(,)(\s[A-Z]\w+\:)", "/$2"),"/:"), "Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col5, Col6, Col8, Col10 where Col5 <>''"))
```

See if that works for you?

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Hi @JPV sorry had to change my form which has added yet another layer of complexity here given that there are multiple 'reasons for claim' and 'products impacted' being entered against one customer and PO number e.g. in the same row. I have update the outputs in the breakdown tab which is how the info will flow in https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g2gJ2lwSV0biCilPipgovarjK7qDzIO-QfQHbWpvnM4/edit#gid=219062088 (Let me know your thoughts - might have to just change the form design instead to have people submit multiple times one PO number?)

Comment: Rearrange the form data on a new tab (see tab 'DATA') then reference that tab in the formula I provided and see if that works.

Comment: Glad to hear I was able to help. If that solved it, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Hello @JPV - hope you're well! I am trying to replicate the solution you kindly provided a few months back and got pretty close but still a bit off. If you see example attached I have a 'CLOSE TO OUTPUT' tab in which I am nearly there following the same logic as you'd previously provided. Would really appreciate your help! Thanks - Beth https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jj8_vLM3FDAWJn1x9mvbxDYwv_LDWFjlkLAF0rfLXOI/edit?usp=sharing